# Blend navigation bar colour to background colour (gradient?)

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a navigation bar which is a slightly darker shade to my background colour. I want to have a gradient going from the center to both the right and left sides, so that the rightmost and leftmost bits of the nav bar reach the background colour. Is this possible to do?

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            <!--<a href="#"><img src="tracylogo7.jpg" alt="Millington and Hope" /></a> -->
            <a href="#"><img src="tracylogo5_header.jpg" alt="Millington and Hope" /></a>
        </h1>
        <h2>
            <!--<a href="#"><img src="tracylogo5_header.jpg" alt="Millington and Hope" /></a> -->
        </h2>   
    </div>
    <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="stock.html">Stock</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="box">
            <a href="#"><img src="home1.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" /></a>

            <a href="#"><img src="home3.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2" /></a>

            <a href="#"><img src="home2.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3" /></a>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p class="client">Tel: 0788740&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;E-mail: tjdelane@hotmail.co.uk</p>

    </div>
</div>      
</body>


#nav
{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-width:1px 0;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align:center; 
  background:rgb(161,153,134)
  background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='(#A19986', endColorstr='#ABA390'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#A19986), to(#ABA390)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */ 
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is maybe, however without any code or example to look at this will probably get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. CSS can do gradients with varying degrees of cross-browser success (including linear, radial and color stops). Try this generator to build something: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/